# How much is the "default" margin in \item elements?

Tags: lists, enumerate, itemize

I am struggling to find this value (or function). I am looking into [enumerate](http://tug.ctan.org/macros/latex/required/tools/enumerate.pdf) package. However, the code does not seems to call any parameter related to identation:

```
27 \def\enumerate{%
28 \ifnum \@enumdepth >3 \@toodeep\else
29 \advance\@enumdepth \@ne
30 \edef\@enumctr{enum\romannumeral\the\@enumdepth}\fi
31 \@ifnextchar[{\@@enum@}{\@enum@}
```

I have also seen the [enumitem](http://anorien.csc.warwick.ac.uk/mirrors/CTAN/macros/latex/contrib/enumitem/enumitem.pdf) package, where this seems to be governed by `\listparindent` or `\itemindent`. But I can't find their values either.

Any hint where I can find this? Let me know if this is a duplicate, but my search has been unsuccessful on that respect too.

PS: think of this as an attempt to manually replicate an enumerate environment. I need these values to do that.

Comment: Probably those values are defined in `latex.ltx` or something similar. That's not package specific. From `latex2e.pdf`: "The \leftmargini through \leftmarginvi parameters defie the distance between the left margin of the enclosing environment and the left margin of the list. By convention, \leftmargin is set to the appropriate \leftmarginN when a new level of nesting is entered. The defaults vary from ‘.5em’ (highest levels of nesting) to ‘2.5em’ (fist level), and are a bit reduced in two-column mode."

Comment: The “default” values are stored in the lengths `\leftmargini`, `\leftmarginii`, …, `\leftmarginvi` (depending of the level of list nesting) and are usually defined by the document class.  For `article`, also have a look to `\size10.clo`, …, `size12.clo`.

Comment: On my texlive installation, they are in `texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/article.cls`, lines 337 to 352: `\if@twocolumn
  \setlength\leftmargini  {2em}
\else
  \setlength\leftmargini  {2.5em}
\fi
\leftmargin  \leftmargini
\setlength\leftmarginii  {2.2em}
\setlength\leftmarginiii {1.87em}
\setlength\leftmarginiv  {1.7em}
\if@twocolumn
  \setlength\leftmarginv  {.5em}
  \setlength\leftmarginvi {.5em}
\else
  \setlength\leftmarginv  {1em}
  \setlength\leftmarginvi {1em}
\fi
` But better to look in `texmf-dist/source/latex/base/classes.dtx` where there are some additional comments.

Comment: Oh, much more complicated than I thought! Will look into them. Cheers·

Comment: You should take a look at the `enumitem` documentation to understand how these parameters are interrelated. This package is definitely recommended.

Answer (score 7):

With the `printlen` package you can conveniently print the values of any given length in your favourite unit:

```
\documentclass[
10pt
%11pt
%12pt
]{article}

\usepackage{printlen}

\begin{document}

test

\begin{itemize}
\item test
\end{itemize}

\uselengthunit{pt}
\printlength{\leftmargini}

\printlength{\leftmarginii}

\printlength{\leftmarginiii}

\printlength{\leftmarginiv}

\end{document}
```